# VisualStudio replaces XAML code on entering line (Bug?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I've played with some XAML code and integrated two fonts. (done by instructions from here: [how use icon [Font-awesome] in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305239/how-use-icon-font-awesome-in-wpf))

But now, VisualStudio is chaning my XAML code when im entering a specific line. After the replacement by VisualStudio, my code is broken and will not work.

Studio is only changing this line and the "FontFamily" property.

This happens when the coursor is ON the line, it doesn't matter where it is (e.g. on the "Name" property) and it doesn't matter how the coursor is placed (by mouse or keyboard).

I've made here video (gif) so you can see my issue
https://giphy.com/gifs/l44QjnOUuEu7lA7p6

Im using:

VisualStudio Community 2015 Update3 and it is an UWP Project

My XAML Code:

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button x:Name="btCurrent" Content="Weather refresh" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="WeatherCurrent_Click" Margin="0,50,0,0" FontFamily="Weather Icons"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tboxSearch" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" PlaceholderText="City name"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbLanguage" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbUnits" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="tbWeatherIcon" Text="&#xf003;" FontFamily="{StaticResource WeatherIcons}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="60" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="tbCityName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbCityCountry" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbTemprature" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbClouds" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Weather Icons"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbWind" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Weather Icons"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbHumidity" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbWeather" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Button x:Name="btForecast" Content="Weather forecast" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="WeatherForecast_Click" Margin="0,50,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

My Ressources:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">/Fonts/fontawesome.ttf#FontAwesome</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="WeatherIcons">/Fonts/weathericons.ttf#Weather Icons</FontFamily>
</Application.Resources>
```

**UPDATE:**
After the restart of my computer, VisualStudio does not anymore strange things. Solved my Problem. Thanks for Help!!

Comment: Can't try your project, but it sounds to me that this could come from an Visual Studio Extension.

Comment: You can pretty much figure out it's not supposed to do this.  It's an extension, or your install is broke af.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this