# Adding fontAwesome to wpf

Tags: wpf, font-awesome

I installed the Font-awesome-wpf package via the NuGet Package Manager, am trying to add an the exchange icon with the code below
`<fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Exchange" Width="30" Height="30" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top"></fa:ImageAwesome>`
but it shows an error.
"Error  XDG0003 Could not load file or assembly 'FontAwesome.WPF, Version=4.7.0.37774, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0758b07a11a4f466' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. CurrencyConverter_static"

`<fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Exchange" Width="30" Height="30" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top"></fa:ImageAwesome>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how use icon \[Font-awesome\] in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305239/how-use-icon-font-awesome-in-wpf)